# Bind a function in parent to a mouse event in child in react (hooks)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn how to bind functions in reactjs to events set in child. The one canvas (`canvas2`) has a mouse move event and the other canvas (`canvas1`) shall receive data from that event when there is any (=mouse moves).

But none of the functions are called and console.log doesn't show up.

Parent App.js

```
const [move, setMove] = useState();

const handleMove = (e) => {
    console.log(e); //shows nothing
    setMove(e.target);
}

return(
<>
    <Canvas1 move={move} />
    <Canvas2 handleMove={handleMove} />
</>
);
```

Canvas1:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.move); //shows nothing
}, [props.move]); //when props.move has new data, I wand this to trigger
```

Canvas2:

```
const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    if(!canvas) {
        setCanvas(initCanvas());
        return;
    }

    canvas.on("mouse:move", props.handleMove); //bind mouse event to parent function
}, [canvas]);

return(
    <canvas></canvas>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Canvas1

Could you try to change `move` and then check the message. (Anything has to be shown up in the console in this way)

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.move); //shows nothing
}, [props.move]); //when props.move has new data, I wand this to trigger
```

#### Canvas2

Could you try this below? and then let me know what message comes up.

```js
const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(canvas);

    if(!canvas) {
        setCanvas(initCanvas()); // This set up a size of the canvas, doesn't this?
        return;
    }

    // canvas.on("mouse:move", props.handleMove); //bind mouse event to parent function
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", props.handleMove);
}, [canvas]);

return(
    <canvas></canvas>
);
```

I'm not sure about this... If you get messages from the code, let me know. I'm trying to find out what problems are

## =========================

-EDITED-

[App.js]

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Canvas1 from "./components/Canvas1";
import Canvas2 from "./components/Canvas2";

function App() {
  const [move, setMove] = useState();

  const handleMove = e => {
    setMove(e.target);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Canvas1 move={move} />
      <Canvas2 handleMove={handleMove} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Canvas1]

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Canvas1 = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`props.move:${props.move}`);
  }, [props.move]);

  return <></>;
};

export default Canvas1;
```

[Canvas2]

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const initCanvas = () => {
  const newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  newCanvas.setAttribute("width", "500px");
  newCanvas.setAttribute("height", "500px");
  return newCanvas;
};

const Canvas2 = props => {
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState();
  const canvasRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!canvas) {
      setCanvas(initCanvas());
      return;
    }
  }, [canvas]);

  useEffect(() => {
    canvasRef.current.addEventListener("mousemove", props.handleMove); // It doens't work
  }, [props.handleMove]);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} />;
};

export default Canvas2;
```

Comment: There's still nothing happening. The problem lays in how do I get the binding of the function up to app.js parent and then the result of that bound function down to the canvas1

Comment: In my code, The message shown up. actually, `undefined` because I didn't assign a value to `move`. 
there is a problem when attach event to the canvas in my code. anyway, `move` had been shown up. can you let me know more code about `move`?

Comment: I think it's working now. By the way, you can write console.log(`props.move:${props.move}`); also as console.log("props.move:", props.move);